# Railsのi18nで訳文が見つからないときに英語を表示させたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsのi18nで日本語の訳文が見つからないときに、英語を表示させたいのですが、可能でしょうか。
viewでデフォルト値や言語の強制指定ができることは知っているのですが、そうではなく、全体的にそういった指定はできないでしょうか。

導入したGemが、日本語に対応しておらず、現時点でja.ymlを作っている時間がないため、とりあえず英語を表示させたいと思うのです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

導入したGemが明記されていないので、Gemについての回答はできませんが、Railsの機能としてはフォールバックという概念でできます。

```
config.i18n.fallbacks =[:en]
```

などを設定するといかがでしょうか。

参考：
[how to use rails i18n fallback features - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223806/how-to-use-rails-i18n-fallback-features)